# Why does my function not execute in python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am relatively new to Python an was using Youtube videos to study. I wrote a small script on my own as follows.

```
def main()
    func1()
    func2()

def func1():
#defininition goes here

def func2():
#definition goes here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Only the `func1()` is executing. I want both of them to execute. Can someone please tell me how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: is there anything inside func1 or func2?

Comment: Both should be executed, paste here full code to get help

Comment: Why do you think that only one function was invoke?

Comment: I never put functions in (running) scripts. I create a dedicated run.py file which I run, *or* I go to the command line -> import the module ->  call the functions I want manually.

Comment: @Elmex80s Could you provide me a skeleton on how to do that?

Comment: @AnnaA. It is very easy. Create 2 empty .py files. One called run.py, the other called whateveryoulike.py. Put func1 and func2 in the whateveryoulike.py. Now in run.py you put calls to the functions func1 and func2, just like you did in your current main(). Finally run run.py.

Comment: @AnnaA. For the second approach. Put your functions in a module called my_module.py. Now go tot he console and do `import my_module`. Then type `my_module.func1()` and press enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are missing a ":" after `def main()`

And it's executing both function for me when I put a print statement inside both functions.

```
def main():        
    func1()
    func2()

def func1():
    #defininition goes here
    print "in func1"


def func2():
    #defininition goes here
    print "in func2"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

> > > ================================ RESTART ================================
> > >
> > > in func1
> > >       in func2

Comment: @AnnaA : you did not accept my answer. Was that intentional? , just checking.

Comment: sorry, accidently. I have one more question.   
Is there any way in which I could place the declarations of these functions in a seperate .py file and call them from the main funciton?

Comment: @AnnaA.: The tutorial covers this in the chapter about [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Yes absolutely. You can save your functions in separate .py file say func.py and call that file within your main function .py file say main.py.  Then in main.py you could call func.py as `from func import *` and still be able to access func's methods. 
It will be better to go through a tutorial if this doesnt makes sense.

Comment: Better don't do `from func import *`. You will clutter your namespace. Read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) concerning this,

Comment: @Matthias, I do realize that. There are several ways to do it. I was expressing an easier one. IMHO, the second part of the problem should be put in as separate question so that we don't mutate original Q&A and can answer in more details.

Answer (score 2):

The main method needs a **:** at the end to be completely/correctly declared

```
def main():
```

after that everything will work fine :)

final code: http://ideone.com/t2TmZk

## Edit:

from another file:

create the file  myExampleFuntion.py, then move func1 and func2 there, then in the original file import that doing **import myExampleFuntion.py**

and call them

```
myExampleFuntion.func1()

myExampleFuntion.func2()
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way in which I could place the declarations of these functions in a seperate .py file and call them from the main funciton?

Comment: you are welcome... yes for sure... create the py file or even better a class

Comment: @ ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ Could you provide me with a skeleton on how to do it? i am mostly used to C++ and doing python for the first time.

Comment: Thank you. Just realised it.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
def func1():
    print "Func 1"

def func2():
    print "Func 2"


def main():
    func1()
    func2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Check https://repl.it/GGCE/0

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way in which I could place the declarations of these functions in a seperate .py file and call them from the main funciton?

Comment: Yes, you can create different .py files, then you can import

for example:

import func1
import func2

def main():
    func1.func1()
    func2.func2()